# Mostrar todo evento do dia em um pdf

Tags: android-studio

estou fazendo um projeto no android Studio onde gostaria de fazer um relatorio que mostrar-se todos os eventos do dia que foi cadastrado. Por exemplo cadastrei cinco nomes hoje quando gerar-se o pdf mostrar-se os cincos nomes

Comment: Que dia? O dia atual? Pode explicar melhor o que está tentando fazer e o que já tentou (se tentou)?

Comment: Bem vindo, aprenda mais sobre a plataforma aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour